# Contact form 7 shortcode not rendering

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

Contact from 7's shortcode not working while other shortcodes are working fine like wpforms lite etc. Shortcode is visible instead of the form.. i need the captcha functionality of contact-from-7  so i cant use wpforms.

Comment: did you check your theme has the_content or echo get_the_content? to display the page/post content, if you get_the_content then this template won't render the shortcode. You can use echo do_shortcode(get_the_content());

Comment: wpform lite shortcode is working.. and contact form 7 was also working before but after deleting  my old files and database from live server and updating it with the new files and database it stopped working

Comment: you delete the contact posts? If then create new one again.

Comment: tried everything.. deleted the plugin installed again created a new form still the shortcode is rendering for contact form 7... wpform lite is working fine